# Why my result is not being written into a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I have the below code for comparing a number of files two by two, and I want to write my results (the last two lines) to a text file. But the  outcome file is empty. Anyone has any idea why?

```
import difflib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


mypath="D:\correctfiles\\112\\"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]



length = len(onlyfiles)
for i in range(0, length):
    for j in range(i + 1, length):
        fi = open(mypath + onlyfiles[i])
        fj = open(mypath + onlyfiles[j])
        ilines= fi.readlines()
        jlines= fj.readlines()
        d = difflib.Differ()
        diff_list = list(d.compare(ilines, jlines))
        n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered = 0, 0, 0, 0
        for diff_item in diff_list:
            if diff_item[0] == '+':
                n_adds += 1
            elif diff_item[0] == '-':
                n_subs +=1 
            elif diff_item[0] == ' ':
                n_eqs += 1
            else: 
                n_wiered += 1



        if n_eqs >= (len(ilines))/2 or n_eqs >= (len(jlines))/2:
            if n_eqs != 0:
                fh= open('D:\\outcome.txt', 'w')


                print 'lines files %s: %d  %s: %d' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines))
                print 'adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d '  % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered)
                fh.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're printing the result, and not writing it to the file?

Comment: Can you explain it with more details I cannot understand @alKid

Comment: print outputs to console, not to file. use `fh.write()` instead (;

Answer (score 3):

You are *printing* your text, not writing it to the file object. Use `fh.write()` to write lines to the file:

```
with open('D:\\outcome.txt', 'a') as fh:
    fh.write('lines files %s: %d  %s: %d\n' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines)))
    fh.write('adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d\n' % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered))
```

Alternatively, use the (more obscure and little-used) `>>` print redirection syntax:

```
with open('D:\\outcome.txt', 'a') as fh:
    print >> fh, 'lines files %s: %d  %s: %d' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines)))
    print >> fh, 'adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d' % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered))
```

In both cases, I open the file here in *append* mode, to add new information rather than replace the file contents.

Alternatively, move the file opening *outside* of the `for` loops to truncate it just once, then write lines to the file each loop iteration before closing it *once* after the loop has completed. The `with` statement takes care of closing the file object for you when the `with` block completes or is exited.

Comment: @user2058811: That's because you are re-opening the file in write mode each time, truncating the file before writing the new data. Use `'a'` as the append mode instead, or open the file *once* outside the `for` loops instead of re-opening it each time.

Answer (score 2):

This part here:

```
print 'lines files %s: %d  %s: %d' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines))
print 'adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d '  % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered)
```

Prints the output to console, not to the file.

You can print it to the file, change it to this:

**Python 2.x**

```
print >> fh, 'lines files %s: %d  %s: %d' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines))
print >> fh, 'adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d '  % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered)
```

**Bonus: Python 3.x** - In case someone needs it :)

```
print('lines files %s: %d  %s: %d' % (onlyfiles[i],len(ilines),onlyfiles[j], len(jlines)), file=fh)
print('adds: %d subs: %d eqs: %d ?:%d '  % (n_adds, n_subs, n_eqs, n_wiered), file=fh)
```